# How to fix Error: Expected a value of type 'DatabaseUser', but got one of type '_JsonQuery'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to read from my firestore database. I am getting this error:

```js
Error: Expected a value of type 'DatabaseUser$', but got one of type '_JsonQuery'
```

This is the method ran when trying to read the database:

```js
Future ReadUserinDatabase(String email) async {
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('TEST').where('Email', isEqualTo: "TEST@yahoo.com").get();
final allData1 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('Activity')).toList();
final allData2 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('CustomerID')).toList();
final allData3 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('Email')).toList();
final allData4 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('Role')).toList();
final allData5 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('UID')).toList();
print(allData1);
print(allData2);
print(allData3);
print(allData4);
print(allData5);
}
}
```

The DatabaseUser class:

```js
class DatabaseUser {
  final String CustomerID;
  final String Email;
  final String Role;
  final String Activity;
  final String UID;

  DatabaseUser(
      {required this.Email,
      required this.CustomerID,
      required this.Role,
      required this.Activity,
      required this.UID});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'CustomerID': CustomerID,
        'Email': Email,
        'Role': Role,
        'Activity': Activity,
        'UID': UID
      };

  static DatabaseUser fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DatabaseUser(
      Email: json['Email'],
      CustomerID: json['CustomerID'],
      Role: json['Role'],
      Activity: json['Activity'],
      UID: json['UID']);
}
```

This is the output I get when running the ReadUserinDatabase method

[Read Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muQE6.png)

This is my Firestore structure

[Firestore Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAhMz.png)

I need to keep the user to pass the Role and UID so I can display specific things depending on their Role when they log in. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this way to extract specific items including what you mentioned in your application.
I added a filter to search that Email address.
I hope this way could resolve your question.

```dart
  void getMessagesTest222() async{
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore.collection('Email').where('Email', isEqualTo: '1234@123123123.com').get();
    final allData1 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('Activity')).toList();
    final allData2 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('CustomerID')).toList();
    final allData3 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('Email')).toList();
    final allData4 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('Role')).toList();
    final allData5 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('UID')).toList();
    print(allData1);
    print(allData2);
    print(allData3);
    print(allData4);
    print(allData5);

  }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: When trying this method it does not display any information at all. I am not getting an error but it doesn't seem to be connecting correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to post more information for example the structure of your firebase firestore?

Comment: I have updated the question with with what is being printed on my end along with my Firestore structure and the updated method.

Comment: Could you share how you call this function "ReadUserinDatabase(String email)"? I will check all for you, to see how I could help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692744/flutter-firebase-query-with-class-and-it-dont-excute-print-function-inside-the/72693713#72693713) this link might help you as well.