# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. From fromDocumentSnapshot

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to snapshot the data from firebase firestore by using DocumentSnapshot
but it says `The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

Here's the code

```
class UserModel {
  String groupLeader;

  UserModel({
    required this.groupLeader,
  });

     factory UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({required DocumentSnapshot doc}) {
        return UserModel(
          //Problem Here
          groupLeader: doc.data(["groupLeader"]),
        );
      }
```

Comment: Try maybe `doc.data()["groupLeader"]` ?

Comment: It says `The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').` Even though I add. the "?" before ["groupLeader"]

Comment: Try `(doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)["groupLeader"]`

Comment: Ohh wow there’s no error. But I don’t if it’s work or not I haven’t try. But I appreciate man thank you.

Comment: Please refer to my article => [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692744/flutter-firebase-query-with-class-and-it-dont-excute-print-function-inside-the/72693713#72693713) it might help you a little bit.