# How to get this data from Flutter firebase firestore database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am new to coding, using flutter firebase firestore i want to fetch data (currently manually added from server.
Attaching my code

Main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/screens/PhysicsNew.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/screens/showAnswer.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/screens/physics.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const Quizzy());
}

class Quizzy extends StatelessWidget {
  const Quizzy({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Demo', initialRoute: '/', routes: {
      '/': (context) => Home(),
      '/physics': (context) => Physics(),
      '/physicsNew': (context) => PhysicsNew(),
      '/showAnswers': (context) => ShowAnswer(),
    });
  }
}
```

Physics.dart

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PhysicsNew extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhysicsNew({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PhysicsNew> createState() => _PhysicsNewState();
}

class _PhysicsNewState extends State<PhysicsNew> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> questionList =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('QuestionList').snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
      body: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: questionList,
              builder: (
                BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> Snapshot,
              ) {
                //
                if (Snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (Snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  Text('Loading');
                }
                final data = Snapshot.requireData;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(data.docs[index]['Question']);
                    });
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

Pubspec.yaml

```
name: quizzy
description: Made by *****.com

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

#
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.3 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.20

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

I am trying fetch data manually added from firestore . attaching my database details in image.
[image: db image]

I am new to flutter, tried various things but it gets complicated and messy, so someone who could help me, Help is Apreciated. !

Error I am getting in debug Console

```
E/flutter ( 6922): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.
E/flutter ( 6922): Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.

E/flutter ( 6922): View the documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization
E/flutter ( 6922): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
E/flutter ( 6922): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6922): #1      Firebase.initializeApp
E/flutter ( 6922): #
```

2      main

Comment: What did you try? In the whole code there is no place where you are using firestore

Comment: Please add the missing part(firebase) to this question.  [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647344/how-to-fix-error-expected-a-value-of-type-databaseuser-but-got-one-of-type/72651377#72651377) [Cloud Firestore Website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) some links for your reference.

Comment: i have updated question with error code , please have a look at it now

Answer (score 1):

> Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.

You're not passing any configuration data to the call to `initializeApp`, which means the Firebase SDK can't initialize its connection to your project on the server.

I recommend following the guidance in the Firebase documentation on [setting up the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup), which:

1. Generates a `firebase-options.dart` file by using the `flutterfire` CLI,
2. Then import this `firebase-options.dart` file into your `main.dart`.
3. And finally passes the configuration options to the Firebase SDK like this:

   ```
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
     options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
   );
   ```